# TCP multiplexing or proxying

Tags: tcp

OK, TCP *is* a multiplexed protocol...
I have several applications which need to connect to an appliance which only accepts 16 concurrent TCP connections.

I am in full control of the applications and the network between them and the enter preformatted text hereappliance...

What can I place between my application and my appliance to accept more than 16 connections on one hand, and still cap to 16 connections on the other hand ?

```
+--------+                         +-----+
| App 1  |---(10cnx on tcp/1234)---|     |
+--------+                         |     |                         +-----+
                                   | ??? |---(16cnx on tcp/1234)---| HSM |
+--------+                         |     |                         +-----+
| App 2  |---(10cnx on tcp/1234)---|     |
+--------+                         +-----+
```

Seems impossible to me, but after [that](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/3-really-good-reasons-you-should-use-tcp-multiplexing), I wonder...

Comment: Questions like this are off-topic here since you are looking for something above OSI layer-4, or some modification to an unknown appliance to let it have more than 16 TCP connections. Also, an application may multiplex its data over TCP, but TCP, isn't multiplexed.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin. I'm no network expert, but for me TCP is multiplexed due to the port mechanism. My question might be unclear, and I apologize, I've trouble sorting this out... I'm looking for some network construct precisely at level 4... Again, I think it's impossible, but I wanted to check before striking this out.

Comment: Each port represents a single TCP conversation. An application could multiplex data over a single TCP conversation, but each conversation is independent.

Comment: So this is impossible at strictly level 4... Knowledge about the application layer is needed. Thanks @ron-maupin !

Comment: The application layer, or layer-4 on the end-device, either of which is off-topic. Apparently the network works, and that is where we could help with the router(s) or switch(es). The 16-port restriction on the end-device has nothing to do with the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I place between my application and my appliance to accept more than 16 connections on one hand, and still cap to 16 connections on the other hand ?

An application level gateway that understands the application protocol in question.

Assuming the TCP connections are carrying some kind of request/response protocol the gateway will need to recognise the beginning and end of each request and response, merge the stream of requests from different clients to send them to the device and somehow keep track of which request belongs to which client so it can send the responses back to the correct client.

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need application protocol logic.

one way to do this would be to structure this as an HTTP application.. if you did that your ??? box could be an HTTP intermediary that spoke HTTP/2 on the backside.. then you would only need one connection on that side (and you can arbitrarily mux the active sessions within http/2).